# Placing letters next to a BASH variable

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I am making a find and replace of BASH variables, like this:

```
sed -i "s/$i/$j/g" ./file
```

I want to pad the replacement with the letters "EE", like this:

```
sed -i "s/$i/EE$jEE/g" ./file
```

Unfortunately, this confuses BASH into thinking `$jEE` is the variable. I have tried this:

```
sed -i "s/$i/EE$j\EE/g" ./file
```

However, the \E disappears, so only one "E" appears.

How can I replace `$i` with a `$j` that is surrounded by "EE". E.g.:

```
i = hello
j = EEhelloEE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i "s/$i/EE${j}EE/g" ./file
```